# Show part of next slide using flexislider 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

This has been asked before, but I need the slider to work in this way:
[image]

I need to sldier to be full width and show a snippet of the next slide.

One solution was this:

```
.flex-active-slide + li {
    left: -1%;
    position: relative;
}
```

However its very buggy. Anyone know if this can be done by altering the plugin code?

Comment: post your html code .

Comment: It's basically the same code as in the basic example only I've adjusted the css to make it full width

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something such as:

`$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  itemWidth: 400,
  minItems: 2
});`

Obviously you'd need to calculate how big each item should be though.

Comment: it's got to be responsive that's the problem :/